# jqGrid change default alert text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I was wondering if there is a way to change the default text message "Please, select row" of the `jqGrid` delete dialog to something else. I was able to change the text for when a row selected using the `msg` option and the caption using `caption`, however, I can't seem to change the alert text.

I looked at the `grid.locale-en.js` file and was able to find. It was under:

```
nav : {
    edittext: "",
    edittitle: "Edit selected row",
    addtext:"",
    addtitle: "Add new row",
    deltext: "",
    deltitle: "Delete selected row",
    searchtext: "",
    searchtitle: "Find records",
    refreshtext: "Refresh",
    refreshtitle: "Reload Grid",
    alertcap: "Warning",
    alerttext: "Please, select row",   <-----
    viewtext: "",
    viewtitle: "View selected row"
},
```

I don't want to change it in the js file since other pages use a different instance of the control and so the message needs to be different. I tried overriding it in my `navGrid` options but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.nav,{alerttext:"Here my text for select row"});
```

[Taken from here.](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/change-alert-text)

Answer (score 0):

this can be done while setting navigation options of the grid too.

if you want to do it specific to any single grid or page, then set the "alerttext" and "alertcaption" in grid navigation options. like :

jQuery("#yourgridId").jqGrid('navGrid', '#YourGridPager',
    {

```
  "edit": true, 
  "add": true,
   addCaption: "Your custom add caption",
   "del": true, 
   "search": false,
   "addtext": "custom add text",
   "edittext": "custom edit text",
   "deltext": "custom delete text",
   "alertcap": "Warning caption",
   "alerttext": "Warning text"
```

}

if you want to implement localization , then you can set these text using resources too.